# Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors. How do I add it as a dependency?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Following the docs on [how to set up a gRPC gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway), I find myself stuck at step four of generating the grpc gateway.

Namely, things fall apart when the following line is added:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

The documentation says `You will need to provide the required third party protobuf files to the protoc compiler` - but not actually how do do so.

How do I add `google/api/annotations.proto` as a dependency?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it one way by adding [third party google apis](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/googleapis/) and its content to the root of my project.

Feels wrong, but apparently this [is encouraged](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/1065#issuecomment-544241612)

Comment: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/adding_annotations/#using-protoc

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and i resolved it following this structure :

```
proto
├── google
│   └── api
│       ├── annotations.proto
│       └── http.proto
└── helloworld
    └── hello_world.proto
```

and run the command :

```
protoc -I ./proto \
   --go_out ./proto --go_opt paths=source_relative \
   --go-grpc_out ./proto --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative \
   --grpc-gateway_out ./proto --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
   ./proto/helloworld/hello_world.proto
```

Comment: Did you download those google's proto files from grpc repository manually ?

Comment: Important if you don't have the "google/api" dir at the root of your project and you are managing it another way.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with only copying annotations.proto and http.proto
in the main proto:

```
import "Proto/google/api/annotations.proto";
```

and inside annotations.proto

```
import "Proto/google/api/http.proto";
```

and my folders look like this:
[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

> If you are using protoc to generate stubs, you need to ensure the
> required dependencies are available to the compiler at compile time.
> These can be found by manually cloning and copying the relevant files
> from the [googleapis repository](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis), and providing them to protoc when
> running. The files you will need are:

```
google/api/annotations.proto
google/api/field_behaviour.proto
google/api/http.proto
google/api/httpbody.proto
```

from [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)

for example run in project root
`git submodule add https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis` to get actual version

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio. My proto file hierarchy looks like this:

[image: proto file hierarchy]

I had to adjust the `ProtoRoot` property of the items in the csproj file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\experimental_service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\google\api\annotations.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\google\api\http.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\google\rpc\status.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\protoc-gen-openapiv2\options\annotations.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\protoc-gen-openapiv2\options\openapiv2.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\validate\validate.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\core.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\debug.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\error_reason.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\openapi.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\permission_service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\schema_service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\authzed\api\v1\watch_service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="Protos\" Access="Internal" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: "ProtoRoot" was the key part for me. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when we run protoc .
try to import the dependency when running the protoc command.

[image: proto folder structure]

for this type of structure use

```
>protoc -I . -I pb/google/api --go_out . --go_opt paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out . --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative --grpc-gateway_out . --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative ./pb/*.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/api/http.proto";
```

with the same structure as explained here: https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/adding_annotations/#using-protoc

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your dependencies using [buf](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf). See the following snippet of their documentation:

> You will need to provide the required third party protobuf files to
> the protobuf compiler. If you are using [buf](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf), this dependency can
> be added to the deps array in your buf.yaml under the name
> buf.build/googleapis/googleapis:
>
> ```
> version: v1
> name: buf.build/yourorg/myprotos
> deps:
>   - buf.build/googleapis/googleapis
> ```
>
> Always run buf mod update after adding a dependency to your
> buf.yaml.