# How to enable gRPC-Gateway in Kotlin

Tags: grpc, grpc-gateway, grpc-kotlin

I wanted to test out gRPC to potentially swap our existing system to work with it.

#### The issue

I cloned [grpc-kotlin](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin) to use their examples and chose to set up `hellowworld` example.
Following all the steps, I initialized the server and everything worked as expected.

I then wanted to add [gRPC-Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) into the mix, as we will need to slowly transition into gRPC from an existing REST architecture.

I'm really new to bazel and gRPC so I tried my best to follow the steps, and tried to add the following into the [hello_world.proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/blob/master/examples/protos/src/main/proto/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/hello_world.proto).

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/example/echo"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}
```

Note that when I click into the `import "google/api/annotations.proto";` it takes me to the following file:
[annotations.proto file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahpcs.png)
which seems to be the correct `annotations.proto` file that I've been meaning to use.

However, when I rebuild, I'm getting the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpfRm.png)

#### What I have tried

I manually copied `http.proto` and `annotations.proto` to a folder called `google/api/` inside `proto` as instructed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168350/import-google-api-annotations-proto-was-not-found-or-had-errors-how-do-i-add), but the issue didn't fix itself, as it seems like `http.proto` is trying to import `google/protobuf/descriptor.proto` and then I'm getting an error that that file cannot be found.