# Invalid package name error when compiling generated zio-grpc classes on Scala 2.13.12

Tags: scala, grpc, zio, scalapb

I'm creating ZIO gRPC client service on scala 2.13.12.

I generated classes from .proto's and trying to compile my project and getting this error:

```
[error] C:\Users\arsen\IdeaProjects\voicekit-grpc\target\scala-2.13\src_managed\main\scalapb\tinkoff\cloud\stt\v1\SpeechToText\SpeechToTextProto.scala:10:20: object annotations is not a member of package com.google.api
[error]     com.google.api.annotations.AnnotationsProto,
[error]                    ^
[error] C:\Users\arsen\IdeaProjects\voicekit-grpc\target\scala-2.13\src_managed\main\scalapb\tinkoff\cloud\stt\v1\SpeechToText\SpeechToTextProto.scala:129:22: object annotations is not a member of package com.google.api
[error]       com.google.api.annotations.AnnotationsProto.javaDescriptor,
[error]                      ^
[error] two errors found
```

There is .proto file from API which I want to use in my app:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tinkoff.cloud.stt.v1;
option go_package = "github.com/Tinkoff/voicekit-examples/golang/pkg/tinkoff/cloud/stt/v1";
option objc_class_prefix = 'TVKSR';

import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service SpeechToText { // Speech recognition.
  rpc Recognize(RecognizeRequest) returns (RecognizeResponse) { // Method to recognize whole audio at once: sending complete audio, getting complete recognition result.
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/stt:recognize"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
  rpc StreamingRecognize(stream StreamingRecognizeRequest)
    returns (stream StreamingRecognizeResponse); // Method for streaming recognition.

  rpc StreamingUnaryRecognize(stream StreamingUnaryRecognizeRequest) returns (RecognizeResponse) { // Method to synchronous recognize audio stream. Returns recognition result after all audio has been sent and processed.
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/stt:streaming_unary_recognize";
      body: "*";
    };
  }
}
......
```

There is my build.sbt:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.io.JFile

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "voicekit-grpc",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",

    scalaVersion := "2.13.12",
    Compile / PB.targets := Seq(
      scalapb.gen(grpc = true) -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value / "scalapb",
      scalapb.zio_grpc.ZioCodeGenerator -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value / "scalapb"
    ),
    Compile / PB.includePaths ++= Seq(new JFile("third_party/googleapis/")),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % "1.50.1",
      "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion,
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.3",
      "dev.zio" %% "zio-http" % "0.0.5",
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.16.1",
      "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.16.1",
      "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"
    )
  )
```

There is my plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.6")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" %% "zio-grpc-codegen" % "0.6.1")
```

I searched and manually downloaded external proto dependencies to directory /third_party

I've tried to add multiple paths to external dependencies to PB.includePaths, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manual downloading files try to add the dependency to `build.sbt`

```
"com.google.api.grpc" % "googleapis-common-protos" % "0.0.3" % "protobuf"
```

or

```
"com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % "2.34.0" % "protobuf"
```

Please notice `% "protobuf"` scope.

https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/use-googles-annotations-proto/3302

---

Actually, just add google `annotations.proto` and `http.proto` manually to `src/main/protobuf/google/api`.

https://github.com/senyanyash/zio-grpc-test/pull/1

[Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors. How do I add it as a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168350/import-google-api-annotations-proto-was-not-found-or-had-errors-how-do-i-add)

Comment: It didn't help.Now my build.sbt looks like this, but error is the same. Scala class have been generating, but compilation fails

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.google.api.grpc" % "googleapis-common-protos" % "0.0.3" % "protobuf",

Comment: @senyanyash It's weird. I published the project at https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO77980936 You can see that without this dependency the error is `google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
tinkoff/cloud/stt/v1/speech_to_text.proto:8:1: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.` https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO77980936/actions/runs/7901021450/job/21563757134 and with this dependency the error is different (`RecognizeRequest` etc. are absent) https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO77980936/actions/runs/7901276542/job/21564514965

Comment: @senyanyash You can click on `Run tests` to expand compilation logs. Ignore "Upload dependency graph".

Comment: I understand, but I have no problem with generating classes from main proto. protocGenerate works fine, but on compile It can't find dependent scala or java classes idk

Comment: @senyanyash Could you provide `RecognizeRequest, RecognizeResponse, StreamingRecognizeRequest, StreamingRecognizeResponse, StreamingUnaryRecognizeRequest, RecognizeResponse` etc. so that I could reproduce the behavior you observe (compile errors etc.)?

Comment: https://github.com/senyanyash/zio-grpc-test there is a whole project with dependencies

Comment: @senyanyash Can you just add google proto manually? https://github.com/senyanyash/zio-grpc-test/pull/1

Comment: Now it's working!!! I tried this approach from the beginning, but I don't know why there was an error. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to either generate ScalaPB classes for Google common APIs or use pre generated ones. See https://scalapb.github.io/docs/common-protos/ and https://scalapb.github.io/docs/third-party-protos#there-is-a-library-on-maven-with-the-protos-and-possibly-generated-java-code

Comment: I found appropriate dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.grpc/proto-google-common-protos/2.33.0 with java classes but It's not generating com.google.api.annotations.AnnotationsProto file in protobuf_external_src as in tutorial. Actually protobuf_external_src not creating at all. my build.sbt now looks like this
      "com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % "2.33.0" % "protobuf",
      "com.google.api.grpc" % "proto-google-common-protos" % "2.33.0" % "protobuf-src" intransitive(),

Comment: I guess problem is in the generated package name for AnnotationsProto class. I checked files inside dependency and found out that package name is "com.google.api.AnnotationsProto", not as in generated scalapb class "com.google.api.annotations.AnnotationsProto"

Comment: The com.google.api.AnnotationsProto is the original java class. com.google.api.annotations.AnnotationsProto should be the ScalaPB one. Can you share a minimal project with this approach that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/senyanyash/zio-grpc-test